# It is async but its execution is sequential

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

From tokio webpage:
https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/hello-tokio
I appreciate that this is a tutorial and they have to start somewhere, but just to make sure I understand this code correctly...

```
use mini_redis::{client, Result};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    // Open a connection to the mini-redis address.
    let mut client = client::connect("127.0.0.1:6379").await?;

    // Set the key "hello" with value "world"
    client.set("hello", "world".into()).await?;

    // Get key "hello"
    let result = client.get("hello").await?;

    println!("got value from the server; result={:?}", result);

    Ok(())
}
```

Surely the above code is executing as sequential? The await points ensure that the code doesn't progress until the future is ready...

Comment: Yes that specific code is sequential, but if you had other pending futures, they would be able to run while this code is `await`ing a result.

Comment: Note that "asynchronous" doesn't implies "non-sequential". It only means that the async call will be done "some time in the future", and you're free to do something else in the meanwhile. It's probably the hardest concept to understand in asynchronous programming.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Check out [tokio::join](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.join.html) and [tokio::select](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.select.html) to do more interesting things than `await`.